# Library design: Hiding dependencies

Tags: c++, header, static-libraries

I'm attempting to build a library that uses a third-party library internally, but I do not want to expose and of this third-party library to the user of my library. This way, when the static library is built, the user will only need my header and the compiled library.

How do I deal with private members in my class definitions that are defined in the 3rd party library?

For example . .

## header:

```
#include "ThirdPartyLib.h"
class DummyClass
{
    TypeFromThirdParty tftp;

public:
    bool checkStuff(const float) const;
};
```

## implementation:

```
#include "ThirdPartyLib.h"
#include "dummy.h"    
bool DummyClass::checkStuff(const float t)
{
    return tftp.isOk(t);
}
```

The offending portion is the `#include "ThirdPartyLib.h"` in the header, as then the user of my library will need more than my library.

One way of getting around this might be to forward declare all third party types used in the header and then replace the value types with references, but I'm wondering if there is another  method or design that I am completely overlooking?

Comment: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: are you trying to avoid the situation where the user knows you are using another library - why don't you just build you own library; a wrapper for the 3rd party one?

Comment: Facade pattern is the right way to go, but to implement that in [tag:c++] you'll probably need [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) too.

Comment: @Pandrei The third party library is massive and complex with all kinds of head-hurting build flags and settings. My goal is to make life as simple as possible for the user by hiding all of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "private implementation class" or "pimpl" idiom is one approach. This keeps all mention of the third-party library (and other implementation details) out of the header, at the cost of an extra level of indirection:

```
// header
#include <memory>

class DummyClass {
public:
    DummyClass();
    ~DummyClass();
    bool checkStuff(float t);

private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
};

// source
#include "DummyClass.h"
#include "ThirdPartyLib.h"

struct DummyClass::Impl {
    TypeFromThirdParty tftp;
};

DummyClass::DummyClass() : impl(new Impl) {}

// This must be defined here, since ~unique_ptr requires Impl to be complete
DummyClass::~DummyClass() {}

bool DummyClass::checkStuff(float t) {return impl->tftp.isOk(t);}
```

Another approach is to define an abstract interface, and a factory to create the concrete implementation class. Again, this removes all implementation details from the header, at the cost of an extra indirection:

```
// header
#include <memory>

struct DummyInterface {
    virtual ~DummyInterface() {}
    virtual bool checkStuff(float t) = 0;

    static std::unique_ptr<DummyInterface> create();
};

// source
#include "DummyClass.h"
#include "ThirdPartyLib.h"

struct DummyClass : DummyInterface {
    TypeFromThirdParty tftp;
    bool checkStuff(float t) {return tftp.isOk(t);}
};

std::unique_ptr<DummyInterface> DummyInterface::create() {
    return std::unique_ptr<DummyInterface>(new DummyClass);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly the facade pattern or building a wrapper for the 3rd party lib...isn't it?

Comment: @Pandrei: Yes, these are wrappers for the library, and if you like patterns then you could regard them as the Bridge, Factory or (a somewhat degenerate example of) Facade patterns.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: could it be seen as `Adapter` or `Proxy` too ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I don't know, I don't really think in terms of 90s-style OO patterns.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I have the same issue, thus my question; it's always unclear to me :/

Comment: @MikeSeymour fantastic answer that begs the follow up question, when is it best to use which? I guess pimpl has the advantage of allowing the user to make Dummy on the stack.

Comment: @learnvst: I prefer pimpl for that reason, and because historically a factory used to require the user to deal with nastier things than `unique_ptr`, but neither is particularly better than the other.