# How to use SDL2 functions in another DLL for main Executable?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, sdl-2, dynamic-linking

I have two projects files. Main project is executable and using my dynamic library project. My DLL project has `SDL2` and is working correctly. My main project doesn’t have `SDL2`. It just has my DLL file. I tried to output from DLL with `SDL2` and it’s working correctly. But, the executable program is giving this error:

> “SDL.h no such file or directory”.

Executable program trying to use DLL’s includes. Why? I don’t want it. **I just want to use SDL2 in my DLL and calling them from executable.**

E.g.
I create Window class in my DLL and its using SDL2 functions. Executable just loading my DLL and using Window class without SDL2 defines. How can i do this?

My Console class like this:
[From DLL SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXMCs.jpg)

If i call Console in executable then IDE wrote error "SDL.h no such file or directory".
[From executable SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbZmw.jpg)

Comment: Probably one of the dll headers includes SDL headers. You should carefully design public interface of dll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Library design: Hiding dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401372/library-design-hiding-dependencies)

Comment: @VTT Yep. One of the my DLL headers includes SDL headers. And i want to use my DLL in main program(executable) without includes SDL headers in my main program. How can i do this? Same thing is working on C# but i can't in C++.

Comment: There can not be any "Same thing" in C# because it does not have headers. As I wrote above, you need to carefully design dll headers so user code including those headers will not include SDL headers or other implementation details of your library. It is also not a good idea to post text as images.